# Magento: some attributes not show in the category page

Tags: magento, filter, attributes, filtering

I have Magento 1.9.1 and I create some new attributes for my products.
I selected "Filtrable (with results)" in the "Use in Layered navigation" in "Frontend Proprieties". My products have the values for this attribute BUT this attribute there is not in the left column in the category page!
If I select "Filtrable (without results)", I see the attributes but with zero results:

Myattribute
- value1 (0)
- value2 (0)
- value3 (0)

Why?

Comment: Did you run indexing after attributes were created.

Comment: Did you add the attributes in to the attribute set? if not please add and try re-indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please attribute admin property "**Visible on Product View Page on Front-end**" set as "**Yes**" and check again.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you need to reindex your attributes. You can do this quickly and easily through Magento's `indexer.php` script:

```
php -f shell/indexer.php -- --reindex catalog_product_attribute
```